# Image showing with specific file name and directory from variable - PHP CodeIgniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I have this function:

```
public function tambah($reg)
{
    $regs = (object) $reg;
    $id = $this->insert_registrasi_data($regs);
    $code = $this->barcode($regs->No_Registrasi);
    if($id){
        $data_session = array (
            'No_reg' => $regs->No_Registrasi,
            'Nama' => $regs->Nama_CTKI,
            'Negara' => $this->format_idNegara_namaNegara($regs->ID_Negara),
            'Jenis_Kelamin' => $regs->Jenis_Kelamin,
            'Umur' => date('Y') - date('Y', strtotime($regs->Tanggal_Lahir)),
            'Code' => $code
            );
        $this->session->set_userdata($data_session);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The data _session('code') is the file name that generated by this function:

```
public function barcode($bcode)
{
    //load library
    $this->load->library('zend');
    //load in folder Zend
    $this->zend->load('Zend/Barcode');
    //generate barcode
    //Zend_Barcode::render('code39', 'image', array('text'=>$bcode));
    $imageResource = Zend_Barcode::draw('code128', 'image', array('text'=>$bcode), array());
    $code = time().$bcode;
    $store_image = imagepng($imageResource,"./asset/barcode/{$code}.png");

    return $code;
}
```

Those code are working fine and the image is saved properly.
What I'm trying to do is to load the saved image. Here's my current code in view file:

```
<img src="./asset/barcode/"<?php $this->session->userdata('Code'); ?>".png"
```

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting an error? You are setting 'Code' but then running the call as 'code'. That session value will never be found if you don't use proper casing.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '/' in C:\xampp\htdocs\amc\application\views\program\administrasi\registrasi_sukses.php on line 16. That's my error. Thanks for pointing the lower case, i updated my code

Comment: And what is the content of C:\xampp\htdocs\amc\application\views\program\administrasi\registrasi_sukses.php in line 16?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should echo the userdata and I would recomend you to try the following:

In the function:

```
$store_image = imagepng($imageResource,base_url("asset/barcode/{$code}.png"));
```

in the view:

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url('asset/barcode/'.$this->session->userdata('Code').'.png'; ?>" />
```

This way you don't have `'` & `"` conflicts and the base_url() makes the code more reusable. Assuming your project is like:

```
/codeigniter_folder/assets/barcode/
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is working. But actually before I use your solution im using this:
<?php $pic = base_url('asset/barcode/'.$this->session->userdata('Code').'.png'); ?>
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-10">: <img src="<?php print_r($pic); ?>"></div>

Comment: You are welcome! Simply do in one line without var $pic: `<div class="col-xs-8 col-md-10"> <img src="<?php echo base_url('asset/barcode/'.$this->session->userdata('Code').'.png'); ?>"></div>`